# How to link a component across all screens?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I would like to know how can I link a component on top of the `BottomTabBar` across all screens? I have a mini player that will expand as on Spotify or Youtube but I can't find a way to link it with  the tab bar

is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Just place your component outside of the navigator!

```js
<Provider store={store}>
  <View>
     <AppNavigator />
     <SomeComponent />
  </View>
</Provider>
```

Comment: @tobiaas this will overlay the TabBar and I can't access it

Comment: @MarkusHayner you will need to position it absolutely that it doesn't overlay the TabBar of course!